# Trimming and batch converting arbitrary video files to WebMs with python and ffmpeg

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, video-encoding, webm

I've got a whole lot of video files that I want to break up into multiple WebMs, each containing a trimmed portion of a specific video.

I plan on having a csv file attached to each video file (having the same filename as the video) with a column structure similar to:

Start Time | End Time | Rotation | Output Filename

And I want to parse the csv files using python to execute ffmpeg, and I did a quick search and found the ffmpeg-python library and thought it might do the trick. The problem is, I don't know the first thing about ffmpeg or video encoding. I've tried reading through the ffmpeg documentation and trying to replicate stuff using ffmpeg-python but the furthest I can get is an output video of the same format as the input file, trimmed (but mpv still shows the duration as the duration of the original file but cuts off playback when the end of the trim is reached) and without audio.

As a side note, I currently use a software named "WebM for Retards" (excuse the offensive title) which uses ffmpeg and I'm happy with its output but it's very tedious for my requirement. However I noticed that these are the arguments passed by using the software:

```
-f nut -i pipe:0   -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 8 -slices 4 -metadata title="This is a title" -ac 2 -c:a libvorbis -qmin 28 -crf 30 -qmax 32 -qcomp 1 -b:v 0 -qscale:a 3 -f webm -y "C:\Output.webm"
```

I'd be happy if I could replicate output similar to what this provides. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I know nothing of ffmpeg-python, but your command creates VP8 video and Vorbis audio. Is this what you prefer? Newer generation is VP9 (libvpx-vp9) and Opus (libopus), but downside is encoding slowness. See [FFmpeg Wiki: VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) for more general info.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I see, what do I have to gain from upgrading? The speed is important but I can sacrifice it if the gain is worth it. EDIT: Checked the link and yeah the upgrade seems to be worth it. But I have no idea how to get this implemented using Python.